# CGEventTap receiving posted event with corrupted CGEventFlags

Tags: macos, cocoa

My application intercepts user input (`CGEvents`) with `CGEventTap`. It also emits `CGEvents` to perform user input.

I noticed that if I were to emit a `CGEvent` I created, the `CGEventTap` receives the event with a different flag than if they were from an actual key press. Why is this so? How do I address this?

Program:

```
import Cocoa
import Carbon

func createEventTap() {
    func callback(proxy: CGEventTapProxy, type: CGEventType, event: CGEvent, refcon: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) -> Unmanaged<CGEvent>? {
        print(event.flags)

        return Unmanaged.passUnretained(event)
    }

    let eventMask = (1 << CGEventType.keyDown.rawValue)
    let eventTap = CGEvent.tapCreate(tap: .cghidEventTap, place: .tailAppendEventTap, options: .defaultTap
                                     , eventsOfInterest: CGEventMask(eventMask), callback: callback, userInfo: nil)!
    let runLoopSource = CFMachPortCreateRunLoopSource(kCFAllocatorDefault, eventTap, 0)
    CFRunLoopAddSource(CFRunLoopGetCurrent(), runLoopSource, .commonModes)
    CGEvent.tapEnable(tap: eventTap, enable: true)
}
 
createEventTap()

DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .seconds(2), execute: {
    let event = CGEvent(keyboardEventSource: nil, virtualKey: CGKeyCode(kVK_Space), keyDown: true)!
    event.flags = .maskShift
    event.post(tap: .cghidEventTap)
})
```

Actual Output:

```
CGEventFlags(rawValue: 537001984)
```

Expected Output (when typing `Shift-Space` manually):

```
CGEventFlags(rawValue: 131330)
```

Comment: There are some extra flags. `537001984` is hexadecimal `0x20020000`, `131330` is `0x20102`. `.maskShift` is `0x00020000` and still there. `0x00000002` is `NX_DEVICELSHIFTKEYMASK` and `0x00000100` is `NX_NONCOALSESCEDMASK`.

Comment: @Willeke ah ok, looks like hammerspoon is aware of this as well https://github.com/Hammerspoon/hammerspoon/blob/b03d628f792eb88188962643c32a490f1174c10d/extensions/eventtap/libeventtap_event.m#L1569